# how do I save/refer to estimates and SE in the output of the lsmeans function in R

Tags: r, mixed-models, random-effects

I am using the lsmeans function to investigate a time-dependency in my data:

```
lme=lme(attraction~factor(time),random=~1|id, data=na.exclude(subject))  
lme.lms=lsmeans(lme, "time")
summary(lme.lms)

time    lsmean         SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL  
   1 0.5823399 0.01805961 NA 0.5469394 0.6177403  
   2 0.5662435 0.01805961 NA 0.5308430 0.6016439  
   3 0.5225464 0.01805961 NA 0.4871459 0.5579468  
   4 0.4938745 0.01805961 NA 0.4584740 0.5292750  
   5 0.4884408 0.01805961 NA 0.4530403 0.5238412  
   6 0.5079754 0.01805961 NA 0.4725749 0.5433758  
   7 0.4521263 0.01805961 NA 0.4167258 0.4875268  
   8 0.4604106 0.01808727 NA 0.4249559 0.4958653  

 ![plot(lme.lms)][1]
```

**I need to transpose the X and Y axis of this plot so that lsmean is on the Y-axis and time is on the X-axis.  I don't know how to do this without finding a way to save the lsmean estimates and the SE outputs as their own objects first. But, I can't figure out how to do this.**

For other functions, I might be able to do something like `lme.lms$lsmean` and `lme.lms$SE`, but when I try this, I get the following error:

```
Error in subject.lme2.lms$lsmean : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

I have looked online and found that the lsmeans output is of class "lsmobj" but I don't know how to manipulate that class and can't seem to figure it out through what I've read.

Comment: There is apparently a plot method for objects returned from `lmerTest::lsmeans`. Why not just: `plot(lme.lms)`? If that's not what you are looking for then examine the object with `str(lme.lms)` and post the results by editing; NOT in comments; and explain what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
summ = summary(lme.lsm)
```

Then `summ` inherits from `data.frame`, and you can plot it however you want to.

Comment: I probably should also mention that there is an `lsmip` function that will plot the lsmeans in an interaction-plot style.